# Quick way to sum the ith item of a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am looking for an alternative approach of summing the ith item of a list of lists that is feasible over large data sets. Below is an example list and my approach.

```
j=[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3]]

My attempt:
h_0=zip(j[0],j[1],j[2])
h_1=[sum(x) for x in h]
print h_1

Output: [6, 5, 7]
```

`Desired output:[6, 5, 7]`....the same as the output I got but would prefer a different approach as my approach is not feasible given the size of my actual data.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Depending on how important it is that this code be fast and readable, you may want to use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). With a NumPy ndarray, this would be `j.sum(axis=0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with [`*`-operator (unpacking argument list)](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> j = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3]]
>>> zip(*j)
[(1, 3, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 3)]
```

with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*j))
[6, 5, 7]
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*j))) # In Python 3.x
[6, 5, 7]
```

using list comprehension:

```
>>> [sum(cols) for cols in zip(*j)]
[6, 5, 7]
```

---

Using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> a = np.array(j)
>>> a.sum(axis=0)
array([6, 5, 7])
```